# Insert and Update in one query in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select / Insert version of an Upsert: is there a design pattern for high concurrency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593870/select-insert-version-of-an-upsert-is-there-a-design-pattern-for-high-concurr)

I have to insert data from one table to another on the basis of condition.

```
1.If Key is found update records
2.If key is not found insert the record.
```

I am using sql server 2005. So can not use `merge` statement. Please suggest the alternative to achieve this

Comment: The suggested duplicate is for "Insert SELECT" not "Insert/Update" - it's definitely not an appropriate duplicate link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To copy from `SourceTable` to `DesitinationTable`:

```
update  dst
set     col1 = src.col1
from    DestinationTable dst
join    SourceTable src
on      src.Key = dst.Key

insert  DestinationTable 
        (Key, col1)
select  Key
,       col1
from    SourceTable src
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    DestinationTable dst
        where   src.Key = dst.Key
        )
```

Comment: They are two tables not one table.

Comment: probably want to do it inside a transaction but yes

Comment: @MahmoudGamal, how do you know that, its not in the question?

Comment: @Jodrell The OP said `I have to insert data from one table to another on the basis of condition.`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: Good point, answer updated

Comment: Gr8 answer and illustration.. Thanks Andomar

Answer (score 5):

```
IF EXISTS(--Query to check for the existence of your condition here)
BEGIN
  --UPDATE HERE
END ELSE
BEGIN
  --INSERT HERE
END
```

Comment: Will it insert/update entire table data?

Comment: This is a structure to follow. You can do update a single row, a few rows or entire table. All depend on the condition

Comment: I want to check where each row record exist in dest or not. how would you make this condition. I am just stuck here

Comment: Your question is already answered. Or you are not explaining the question properly. Can you show the query that you are using to check the condition?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stored procedure example from [my answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398852/how-to-improve-data-insert-update-performance/12400228#12400228)

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.update_table1 
    @Field1 int, --key1
    @Field2 int, --data fields
    @Field3 int, 
    @Field4 int

    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    update table1 set Field2=@Field2,Field3=@Field3,Field4=@Field4 
            where Field1=@Field1;
    IF(@@Rowcount=0)
    BEGIN
         insert into table1(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4) 
                    values (@Field1,@Field2,@Field3,@Field4);
    END
    GO
```